# Formulario para ingreso de Datos con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Alguien me puede ayudar, tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class Citas2(models.Model):
    laboratorio = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=LABORATORIO_1, null=True)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Pacientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctores, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    examen = models.ForeignKey(Examenes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Examenes(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Este Form que ingreso los examenes:

```
class ExamenesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Examenes
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'descripcion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'codigo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'precio': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Vista para ingresar Examenes

```
class ExamenesCreate(CreateView):
    model = Examenes()
    form_class = ExamenesForm
    template_name = 'examenes.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('laboratorio:consultar_examenes')
```

Form para tratar de ingresar las Citas

```
class OrdenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Citas2
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
           'paciente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
           'doctor': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),          
           'examen': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),          
           'laboratorio': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

Lo que quiero es ingresar varios exámenes por paciente, es decir un paciente puede tener muchos exámenes, esa sería la relación.
es decir en la tabla Citas2:

[image: Tabla Citas2]

Se me complica en la parte de Exámenes ya que debo agregar varios por paciente y no los ingreso sino los busco ya agregados.
 Agradecería a alguien que me de una pauta...

Comment: Cambia el tipo de relación, básicamente si tu relación ahora mismo es de uno a muchos (ForeignKey) entonces cámbiala a muchos a muchos (ManyToMany) es decir, en el modelo Citas2 el campo exámenes sería: `examenes = models.ManyToManyField(Examenes, related_name='citas')`

Comment: Ok gracias, si ya lo realice, cual sería la mejor forma de ingresar los datos por formset?

Comment: Creo que esa pregunta ya viene a corresponder a otra entrada, de todas formas si no tienes algún tipo de error puedes pasarte a leer la documentación de Django para ver como funcionan los [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/)